# Payments and Authorization in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'd like to have pages in the website available only to paid users.
Users will be able to purchase a subscription online and get immediate access to the pages.

How hard will it be to implement this in Apostrophe CMS?
I am a node.js developer

Where can I see all the plugins developed for Apostrophe CMS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its very possible to use Apostrophe for a purpose like the one you're proposing. I have a very similar website already built on Apostrophe, which allows users to create accounts and purchase "subscriptions" in order to get access to certain pages and content.

You would want to start by looking into the Apostrophe Users, Groups, and Permissions modules. Using Apostrophe's built in permissions, you could set up certain groups to have access to whichever pages need restrictions, but disallow non-registered or non-subscribed visitors access to those pages.

At that point, all you would need to do is set up a module to handle the subscriptions (you could use Apostrophe's schemas to "join" a subscription object to each user so that you have easy access to each user's subscription information) and build a page that would contain the actual subscription workflow. If you created your own "subscription" module, you could take care of both of those things at once - you would be able to build a front-end page that could talk to a back-end method on your "subscription" controller. That controller could handle payments, as well as add users that purchase subscriptions to the groups that are allowed to view the restricted content.

There are lots of other ways to create a very similar setup in Apostrophe - one of the things I have loved about it is how flexible and extendable it is. You might want to start off reading the "Getting Started" and "Intermediate Tutorials" in the link below.

https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/index.html